# what will happen at output current ? when two zener diode is in series?

Tags: diodes, zener

"what will be the output current when we connect two zener diode in series "

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5XSEH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

?

Comment: What kind of circuit has zener regulators and no series resistance?

Comment: Nothing will happen. There is no input voltage so there will be no current anywhere in the "circuit" and no output voltage. If you want an answer then you must supply all the relevant details **in the question** and not in the comments.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami: A clamp.

Comment: @EMFields - If you want to see the clamp performing anything useful, you have to model the source resistance.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami: If it's the clamp that's doing the work, it'll clamp at at a particular voltage level regardless of the source impedance.

Comment: @EMFields How will it do that? Without source resistance, ANY voltage at the input, be it 5, 50 or 500V, will appear at that same exact value at the output. The only way a clamp can work is because of source resistance, or interconnection resistance, or both. Whatever the case, it has to be modeled with a resistance, not with a wire.

Comment: It'll clamp  because of its inherent breakdown characteristics, which have only a cursory relationship with the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question with no attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The output current, if there is no load, will always be zero.

The circuit is not complete, you need some kind of power supply on the left side, also some current limiting element like a resistor. And you also need to say what will be connected on the right side.

Tipically you will have a "constant" voltage on the output, and depending on the load you connect, more or less current will flow. In your particular case, you have two 5.1V zeners, so the output voltage will be around 10.2V. If you connect a 1Kohm resistor, for example, you will have a current output of 10.2V/1Kohm = 10.2mA. But this was just an example, you need to complete the circuit.

Comment: its only for reference i want to know suppose my load is near by 10amp and two zeners are 50 watt 12v . then can i get 10 amp output side?

Comment: If what you are trying to make is a 10A 12V power supply, then no, you won't be able to do that like this, that's too much power to be done with a zener shunt. These are 1W Zeners, at most you can get 2W out of such a circuit.

Comment: I think "you need some kind of power supply on the *right* side" should be "you need some kind of power supply on the **left** side". I read the circuit as having the input on the left, and output on the right (also by convention).

Comment: Totally right, gbulmer, it slipped through...

Comment: thank you for your convenience, actually the thing is that we used 24v 50amp battery at input side and there and at output side i want to use two zener 50 watt 12v in series for getting approx 10amp load . is this possible to get 10 amp load at output side? . no issue about voltage we can get it across one of the zener

Comment: If you connect two zeners to the battery, and the zeners make a total voltage that is less than the battery voltage, the zeners will blow up. Doesn't matter if they are 50W, you will get a huge amount of current through them.

Answer (score -1):

Your drawing needs a power supply, a ballast resistor, and a load, but if I interpret what you're asking properly, the output current for the two zeners will be equal to the same current as if you used a single Zener, but at twice the output voltage of a single Zener.

But, more to the point, I'd like to address your interesting comment:

> "its only for reference i want to know suppose my load is near by 10amp
>   and two zeners are 50 watt 12v . then can i get 10 amp output side?"

Yes, you can, and here's how with a single 50 watt Zener:

[image]

and here's the Zener data sheet:

[image]

Comment: And what happens to the Zener in this power supply if there is no load?